# I2C driver support baud rate parameter

Tags: centos

I have several test machines running CentOS release 6.5 (Final) and we are using Python 3.3 using the SMBus package to communicate over the SMBus (e.g., I2C). We are using the i2c-dev module. The problem we are having is the driver is hard coded to 400 kHz and I have found no way to change the baud rate under the /sys/module/i2c_dev directory. I have used something similar to change the I2C baud rate on the Raspberry Pi (i.e.,/sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/baudrate).

So my question is, is there a way to change the baud rate of the i2c_dev module/driver without having to recompile the kernel? If I need to recompile the kernel, how can I add this configuration item so I can change the baud rate by using something similar to what the Raspberry Pi has? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Mark